# UNPIVOT sale's table with Unit and Value for last 6 months

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to pivot a table :

```
CREATE TABLE Sale(      
CustomerNo [Int] Not NULL,
Month [Int] Not NULL,    
Unit1 [Int] Not NULL,    
Value1 [Int] Not NULL,    
Unit2 [Int] Not NULL,    
Value2 [Int] Not NULL,     
Unit3 [Int] Not NULL,    
Value3 [Int] Not NULL,    
Unit4 [Int] Not NULL,   
Value4 [Int] Not NULL,    
Unit5 [Int] Not NULL,    
Value5 [Int] Not NULL,   
Unit6 [Int] Not NULL,    
Value6 [Int] Not NULL)
```

It is the customer data report for the last 6 months and it is populated every  month.The "Month" column refer to the current month 
what I am trying to do is to have a row with 
CustomerNo ,Month,Unit and Value for each month.

This is an example of one customer data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the DML, I'll just give you a generic solution.

```
Declare @Source table (Id int,Full_Load Int,Half_Load Int)
Insert into @Source
select 1,10,5 union all
select 2,20,10 union all
select 3,30,15 
Select * FROM @Source
select Id,Filed_Name,Value from 
@Source
Unpivot
(Value For Filed_Name in([Full_Load],[Half_Load]))
as unpvt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .The problem is I need Unit & Value of each month to be Unpivot against each CustomerNo.Please refer to my example .Cheers.